# Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Tags: selenium-webdriver, grid

I am trying to run a simple program using Selenium Grid(have no prior knowledge of selenium grid), and I am having error shown as below:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DEL1-LTC1X3PH2', ip: '192.168.0.101', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Below is my sample code:

```
String URL = "http://www.DemoQA.com";
String Node = "http://192.168.1.164:4444/wd/hub";
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
//cap.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Node), cap);

driver.navigate().to(URL);
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.quit();
```

Can someone please explain why this error is coming, and any reference from where I can get to know more about selenium grid.

Answer (score 0):

This error looks like it's occurring because you don't have a Selenium Grid running with a hub at the URL you provided. You need to start the grid yourself, Selenium won't start it for you the way it will start up a single session. You can use `docker` and `docker-compose` to start your grid using the instructions [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#via-docker-compose).

You can find more information about Selenium Grid [here](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp).

Also, rather than use

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
```

you can condense to one line and use

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
```

to set up your `DesiredCapabilities`.